# VPython: File Read Error

Tags: python

I'm using VIDLE and VPython.  All I'm trying to do is read the values from "weather.txt."  The values that I need to read start on the second line of the file, so I need to skip the first line.  Here's a snippet of my code:

```
try:
    filename = "‪‪‪C:\Users\Ashley\Documents\weather.txt"
except (ValueError, IndexError), e:
    print e
    sys.exit()

datafile = open(filename, 'r')
datafile.readline()

for line in datafile:
    data = line.split()

    try:
        date = data[2]
        temperature = float(data[3])

        year = float(date[0:4])
        month = float(date[4:6])
        day = float(date[6:8])

        decimalYear = getDecimalYear(year, month, day)

        meanTimes.append(decimalYear)
        meanTemperatures.append(temperature)

    except:
        print "Tossing line", line

datafile.close()
```

And, I keep receiving the following error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "Untitled", line 45
>       datafile = open(filename, 'r') IOError: [Errno 22] invalid mode ('r') or filename:
>   '\xe2\x80\xaa\xe2\x80\xaa\xe2\x80\xaaC:\Users\Ashley\Documents\weather.txt'

Any ideas of what exactly I'm doing wrong?  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you need to escape backslashes in the file path. It would also appear that there are invisible unicode characters at the start of your string.

Try using:
`filename = 'C:\\Users\\Ashley\\Documents\\weather.txt'`

Also, the first `try: except:` block isn't required, there's no way that those exceptions can be raised simply by setting a variable.

Answer (score 0):

The key is in the junk that you see in the error message which was prepended to your filename:

```
'\xe2\x80\xaa\xe2\x80\xaa\xe2\x80\xaaC:\Users\Ashley\Documents\weather.txt'
```

You can investigate what this means at a Python prompt:

```
>>> '\xe2\x80\xaa\xe2\x80\xaa\xe2\x80\xaa'.decode('utf-8')
u'\u202a\u202a\u202a'
```

Google tells me that Unicode code point U+202A turns out to be the ["left-to-right embedding" character](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/202a/index.htm) which is probably one of those zero-width characters and it probably got copy-pasted into your source file somehow. I'd suggest deleting the line with the filename and re-typing it.